# how to get specific object by id from json array of objects?

Tags: android, json, api

Hope you guys can explain me, I'm doing this JSON first time and have 2 more days to complete.

```
        bookByID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBookbyid);
        btSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSearchbook);
        etId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etID);
         queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        btSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadBook();
            }
        });
    }

    private static final String JSON_URL = "deleted";
```

This is method:

```
    private void loadBook() {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        int id = Integer.parseInt((String) etId.getText().toString());
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL + id, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
```

Sorry for this spacing but it keeps saying that I'd have to explain all code

```
                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
                    for(int i=0;i<object.length();i++) {
                        int bookid = object.getInt("id");
                        String title =object.getString("title");
                        String isbn =object.getString("isbn");
                        String description =object.getString("description");
                        int price =object.getInt("price");
                        String currencyCode =object.getString("currencyCode");
                        String author =object.getString("author");
                        list.add(new Book(bookid,title,isbn,description,price,currencyCode,author));
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello end", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the object by its id in a for loop

```
    private void lookForJsonObj(JSONArray bookArray,int id) throws JSONException {
    for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject book = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);
        int bookId = book.getInt("id");
        if (bookId == id){
            //this is the book you are looking for
            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Update your parsing code with this

```
              JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    int bookid = obj.getInt("id");
                    String title =obj.getString("title");
                    String isbn =obj.getString("isbn");
                    String description =obj.getString("description");
                    int price =obj.getInt("price");
                    String currencyCode =obj.getString("currencyCode");
                    String author =obj.getString("author");
                    list.add(new Book(bookid,title,isbn,description,price,currencyCode,author));
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello end", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Edit by OP:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100,
    "title": "Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction",
    "isbn": "978-0735619678",
    "price": 2954,
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "author": "Mike Riley"
  },
  {
    "id": 200,
    "title": "The Pragmatic Programmer",
    "isbn": "978-0201616224",
    "price": 3488,
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "author": "Andrew Hunt and Dave Thomas"
  },
  {
    "id": 300,
    "title": "iOS Forensic Analysis",
    "isbn": "978-1430233428",
    "price": 4604,
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "author": "Sean Morrisey"
  },
  {
    "id": 400,
    "title": "Ghost in the Wires: My Adventures as the World's Most Wanted Hacker",
    "isbn": "978-0316037709",
    "price": 1493,
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "author": "Kevin Mitnick"
  },
  {
    "id": 500,
    "title": "Handling Unexpected Errors",
    "isbn": "978-0590353403",
    "price": 1399,
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    "author": "Charles R. Ash"
  },
  {
    "id": 600,
    "title": "Android Application Development For Dummies",
    "isbn": "978-0470770184",
    "price": 1979,
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "author": "Donn Felker"
  }
]
```

Comment: Okay, I didn't explain correctly so what I'm trying to do is when you click a Button on my Android Activity, Button takes Text from EditText, and by using that Text which is an ID, opens the book by that ID. I will add more code

Comment: Are you able to fetch the books without an error? If you cant, I will update my answer

Comment: I will let you know tomorrow because I think I found a solution but it's midnight right now so have to go to sleep, have a goodnight ;]

Comment: I still can't manage to make it, I got number format exception for my ID, but don't know how to make it in catch block becose if I make catch block, my URL link doesn't see my int ID...  I wanted to test with POST after that how to pass that curly brackets        ` int id = Integer.parseInt("{" + etID1.getText().toString() + "}");

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL + id, new Response.Listener<String>() { `

Comment: what was your json? do you have a field named "books"? if so checkout my edit. You should be getting an JSONArray from your "response" JSONObject

Comment: Please add your JSON data to your post

Comment: I added my JSON data in the last edit, by the way, it's working fine without JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("books")

Comment: see my edited parsing code again. From the looks of it there should be a problem. Your json response data is an JSONArray, you are trying to parse it to a JSONObject